# Ubuntu hangs on restart, can't reach login screen

Tags: boot, 18.04, startup

I just changed the ownership of several files so I could get a better backup image. I made the backup, restarted my machine, and this now flashes on my screen for a second and then goes black for 5 seconds, and repeats.
[I can't copy code, ofcourse, so here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nLg0.jpg)

What does any of this mean? I can get into recovery mode, but I don't know what do do from there. I tried several solutions, like removing Plymouth, but no dice.

UPDATE: I'm trying the solution [here](https://muaadelsharif.blogspot.com/2016/09/how-to-fix-and-prevent-devsda1.html) but the booted desktop stops responding after 5 seconds.

UPDATE2: I just tried my backup on a spare computer and it now has the exact same problem.

Update3: [requested image](https://i.postimg.cc/gjxPPQqP/20200412-222919.jpg)

Comment: Is this about a supported version of Ubuntu or are you running Linux Mint? I ask because most errors pertain to `timesyncd`, which is installed by default in Mint and not Ubuntu. Questions about Mint are off-topic BTW.

Comment: This is ubuntu. I used mint before and switch to ubuntu proper a while ago

Comment: Did you run `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service` as suggested by the error messages? If so please include the output in your question.

Comment: Sorry for the late repose. I did and here is the result: https://i.postimg.cc/gjxPPQqP/20200412-222919.jpg

Comment: Are you able to add it to the question as text, please? I can't open your link.